# Relationship between expected minimum as sample size increased

Tags: probability, expected-value, sample, extreme-value

Suppose I have $N$ random variables $X_i$, $i = 1, \dots, N$. I am interested in the quantity
$$ A = \mathbb E \left[\min_{i=1, \dots, N} X_i \right]. $$

Now suppose I take a subset $S \subset \{1, \dots, N\}$ of variables and calculate the expected minimum of those
$$ B = \mathbb E \left[ \min_{i \in S} X_i \right]. $$

I was wondering if a relationship can be found between $A$ and $B$. If it is required to assume that $X_i$ has been realised then that is fine. I've been trying to use the relationship
$$ \mathbb E \left[ \min_i X_i \right] \leq \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \sum_i \mathbb E X_i^p \right]^\frac{1}{p}. $$
But I cannot get equality out as I get that result using Jensen's inequality, which makes getting a relationship from it difficult.

Comment: If we make your notation a little more precise and write $A(N)$ to reflect how $A$ depends on $N$, and let $m$ be the cardinality of $S$, then $B=A(m)$. Their relationship depends on $N$, $m$, *and the underlying distribution,* as described in any account of [Extreme value distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) and the Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko theorem.